# Spring Boot JMS - when should a message be sent on a @Transacted method?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, jms

I was wondering on a Spring Boot method marked as @Transactional, when should a message appear on the queue? I’m asking because I’ve noticed 2 different behaviours on 2 different applications.

Both applications have the following in common:

- Spring Boot 2.0 based
- JMS message sending is using JmsTemplate, with setSessionTransacted set to true
- No explicit transaction settings configured
- There is a Mongo DB used (using Spring Data) and a record is being modified in the same method as the message is sent

The major difference between the two applications is:

- One has a JPA data source (using Spring Dataj and a record is read and/or written in this method. The other application does not have this data source.

The difference in observed behaviour is that when the JPA source is present, the message is sent at the end of method. Without it, the message is sent immediately.

Is this the expected behaviour?

Can I configure the applications to behave the same way? Ideally I’d like the message to be sent at the end (so any Mongo changes that fail would cancel the message send and rollback any JPA changes made)? I realise that Mongo changes are not part of any transaction created.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With JMS and a DB you have two resources.

To have a full transactional behavior you need distributed transactions support.

If you don't have this even when the message is sent as last operation if the sending fails the data is changed in the database anyway.

To configure distributed transaction you need JTA. This is described here:

With JMS and a DB you have two resources. To have a full transactional behavoir you need distributed transactions. We use Bistronix in our application and this works very well.

Have a look at the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-jta.html

Comment: I actually just want to know about this behaviour and why it is different in each case, and how to make it the same if possible.